# forward subdomain to specific server

Tags: dns, internet, routing, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward remote desktop traffic to a particular computer inside a network. Is there a way to point or forward a sub domain to a specific computer inside a network?
For example if I have 3 computers inside a network, I cannot forward the default RD port to all 3 computers. I also know that you cannot point a sub domain say "RD1.mydomain.com" to "MYIP:port" as DNS does not allow for port number. Is there any other way to forward traffic to a particular address or IP with a port number.
I have a domain name through go daddy but it will not allow me to forward a sub domain to anything other than a "http" or "https"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you cannot assign a domain name to a specific port, at least not without reverse proxying or some other crazy setup.

If you are interesting some info on the proxy idea, check out this other SU question: [How can I map a domain name to an IP address and port?](https://superuser.com/questions/394078/how-can-i-map-a-domain-name-to-an-ip-address-and-port)

Specific to your RDP scenario: You best bet is to either use different listening ports for each RDP server (easiest), or get multiple IP addresses from your ISP and set them all up in your router with proper port forwarding, and then assign (sub)domain names to those IP addresses.

Some Related SU questions:

- [Using Remote Desktop to connect to different computers behind same IP](https://superuser.com/questions/393939/using-remote-desktop-to-connect-to-different-computers-behind-same-ip)
- [How do I change the RDP listening port?](https://superuser.com/questions/63107/how-do-i-change-the-rdp-listening-port)

Comment: Multiple ip addresses really is not an option for me. For now I have been using port numbers, such as domain.com:7100 but I would rather do something like computername.RDP.domain.com without a port number in the address

Comment: As I said in my answer, without some slightly convoluted proxy work, that's just not going to happen. Domain names point to an address, not an address + a port.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 servers: server1 with ip 192.168.1.10, server2 with ip 192.168.1.11, server3 with ip 192.168.1.12 you can port forward into your router so that you have 3 diffrent external ports open that go to port 3389(default rdp port) for each machine.
Example:

- For server 1 you can put external port 3389 and internal 3389 for ip 192.168.1.10.
- For server 2 you can put external port 3390 and internal 3389 for ip 192.168.1.11.
- For server 3 you can put external port 3391 and internal 3389 for ip 192.168.1.12.

Note you need to port forward tcp and udp.
Then add an A record for your domain pointing to the public ip of your network and you will be able to connect to your server.

- For server 1 it's going to be mydomain.com:3389
- For server 2 it's going to be mydomain.com:3390
- For server 3 it's going to be mydomain.com:3391

Comment: I don’t see the word “domain” anywhere in your post. Can you elaborate on how this addresses the question? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.